# I'm Looking for a Simple Tutorial on Saving a Text File from a URL to my Android Device

Tags: android

I need to save a text file from my website to my Android device. I can't seem to find something that explains this process well to a newbie like me. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: clarification: are you grabbing data via the network (website) and then want to save that data to the phone as a textfile? (or in a db, or alter phone data)\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your manifest file..

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

this example is to display the textfile in android..
it uses asynctask

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Display extends Activity implements
        OnClickListener {
    Button button;
    TextView outputText;

    public static final String URL =
        "URL";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewsById();

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTxt);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
            }
            return output;
        }

        private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(stream));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                    output.append(s);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            outputText.setText(output);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Hope I can wrap my head around exactly how it works.

Comment: Is there some kind of step-by-step break down of what is going on here? I don't quite understand this

Comment: just see the asynctask in android which is used to run asynchronous from ui thread and then see the url and http  connection and finally see the reading text file

Comment: when i clicked the button it showed my text file's content in the textview area...but its like complete magic..i dont get what happening here???

Comment: dude...try to learn the code step by step